# Traduzir parte especifica do template woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Olá.. não estou conseguindo achar o arquivo para traduzir o texto "Product successfully added to your cart." Junto com o botão "Continue Shopping".

ps.: Já tentei abrir varios arquivos de linguagem no poedit mas mesmo assim sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Va no `woocommerce-functions.php` e procure a função que contem a propriedade `'woocommerce_add_to_cart_message'` para mudar a mensagem *"Product successfully added to your cart."*

Para a mensagem no botão procure a função `my_cart_messages` nesse mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Nunca, jamais, de forma alguma edite um plugin diretamente, caso o contrário vai perder a modificação sempre que ele for atualizado ou pior, vai ficar sem atualizar e provavelmente correndo o risco de segurança, que já várias correções de segurança estando sendo sempre feitas.

Comment: Valeu pela dica @ClaudioSanches!

Comment: Em qual diretorio fica esse arquivo @DHEKU ?

Comment: E como deveria ser feito para não editar diretamente então @ClaudioSanches ?

Answer (score 1):

Atualize seu WooCommerce da versão 2.3.5 para 2.3.7 que é a última versão.
Provavelmente vai mostrar o aviso para atualizar a tradução também, se não aparecer, vá até **WooCommerce > Status do sistema > Ferramentas** e clique no botão *Forçar Atualização de Tradução*.
Esta última versão do WooCommerce esta 100% traduzida para Português do Brasil. Além que tem 99% do frontend traduzido para Português de Portugal.

Desta forma tem que funcionar.

Entretanto se ainda não estiver funcionando, isso pode estar sendo alterado por algum plugin ou pelo seu tema.
Neste caso recomendo você tentar traduzir com o plugin [Codestyling Localization](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/).

Comment: Puts não deu certo com a atualização forçada @ClaudioSanches.

E eu instalei esse plugin mas ele apenas promete salvar as traduções feitas, não encontrei um meio de traduzir ume parte especifica.

No plugin do ecommerce ele esta dando a seguinte mensagem.. Warning: printf() [function.printf]: Argument number must be greater than zero in /home/wanderci/public_html/ecommerce/wp-admin/includes/update.php on line 289

Nao dando dessa maneira atualizar. Sabe me dizer como resolver??

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar o arquivo para editar esses textos! Segue o caminho..

```
/wp-content/themes/seutema/includes/theme_woocommerce.php
```